# Can we improve variance estimate by using sample kurtosis?

Tags: variance, kurtosis

The sample variance is the minimum variance unbiased estimator and its variance is related to kurtosis
$$\operatorname{Var}(S^2) = \frac1n\left(\mu_4 -\frac{n-3}{n-1}\sigma^4\right)$$

Is there some theory that uses sample kurtosis to improve the sample variance estimate, in whatever sensible sense (MSE maybe?) ? It'll be biased of course.

Comment: Reminds me of James-Stein estimation, where the first moment (sample mean) is adjusted with a correction factor associated with a higher (second) moment of type $1-(k-2)/\sum_ix_i^2$. I do not know anything specific, but may be you can search along these lines.

Comment: Not directly relevant, but note that for sampling from a normal distribution, $\frac1{n+1}\sum(x_i-\bar x)^2$ is a better MSE estimator of variance than using $\frac1{n-1}$ or $\frac1n$